# Is this some sort of bot?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

The (ex-)user "Dave Mar" copied a comment of mine from one of my questions and posted it as an answer; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538316/dropdownlist-in-gridview-not-available-when-editing/1270376#1270376)'s the link. He lists his web site as being my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: Could one of your co-workers be playing a joke on you?  I'm seeing a fair amount of activity on the site coming from your company.

Comment: I don't think it's a coworker. The large amount of activity isn't surprising. It's a really big company.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it. The surname "Mar" looks like the month you posted. Very dodgy. I'll delete the account and flag it...

For info, this would have been fine as a "flag for moderator attention" (or whatever the button is called), but MSO is OK too.

Comment: Thanks. If it happens again, I'll flag it.